# Matching a number a max number of times

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following regex in Perl that works for matching strings with 6 or fewer digits in them.  However, this also matches strings with more than 6 digits.

`$string =~ /[0-9]{1,6}/`

Matches:

1. T12345#1
2. 0897
3. 112355501234

I'd like the regex to match the first 2 but not the last case.

Comment: T12345#1 is not exactly a number. Do you want partial match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a negated look ahead to see if a digit follows, and negated look behind so you don't just match the last six digits:

```
$string =~ /(?<!\d)\d{1,6}(?!\d)/
```

Comment: Nice. You should explain the regex and lookarounds (negative look behind etc. ) a bit more ... for great justice and many ++ :-)

Comment: Made this to do it in javascript (no look-behind) - `(^|\D)\d{1,6}(\D|$)`. Not as elegant, but it takes care of OP's examples :) One thing I wondered the first example has 5+1 digits. What if it had been 5+2? I.e. `T12345#12` - is that a match in OP's eyes?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. If the string is `T12345#12`, Daniels answer would find `12345` and `12`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it this way:

```
$string =~ /^(?!.*\d{7}.*).*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  just want to reject strings that contain more than six decimal digits then you can use `tr///` to count them

```
if ( $string =~ tr/0-9// <= 6 ) { ... }
```

But you don't make it clear whether separate numeric substrings should be counted together. You say `T12345#1` is valid, but what about `T12345#12345`?